# Does AUC/ROC curve return a p-value?

Tags: p-value, roc, auc

When reading [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4820488/), I noticed that the legend in Figure 3 gives a p-value for each AUC (Area Under the Curve) from the ROC (Receiver Operator Characteristic) curves. It says:

> The area under the curve (AUC) is 1.0 (p < .001) for the overall
>   D-IRAP scores, 0.95 (p < .001) for the female picture bias scores and
>   0.94 (p < .001) for the male picture bias scores.

I'm helping a friend who is developing a similar study. To draw the ROC curves and calculate their AUC, I'm using the R `pROC` package, which has a function called `roc()` which returns a `roc` object. Analyzing this `roc` object, however, I couldn't find anything similar to a p-value. What am I missing? How did the authors of the cited article come to that p-value? I couldn't find anything in their methods. Does ROC curves usually come with a p-value?

Comment: You won't usually find p-values with AUROC estimates, it is not really common practice, so you should delve deeper into the article to see how they did it. Possible solutions: simulations or a statistical test (for ex. proportion test).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. `p-values` from ROC areas are new to me, but I read the following:

[Mason and Graham (2002)](https://doi.org/10.1256/003590002320603584) show that the ROC area is equivalent to the Mann–Whitney U-statistic testing the significance of forecast event probabilities for cases where events actually occurred with those where events did not occur.
Function [`roc.area()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/verification/versions/1.42/topics/roc.area) of R-package `verification` applies this approach and uses function [`wilcox.test()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) to calculate the `p-value`. To me, it looks like this was done in the paper you referenced.